# Anaconda3 Blocked by Group Policy on Windows 10

Tags: windows, group-policy, anaconda, applocker

I'm trying to get Anaconda3 to run in a Windows domain environment. We use Applocker to restrict what can be run. I'm guessing that since Anaconda doesn't install to Program Files or Program Files (x86), AppLocker is catching it. However, I cannot confirm that because there's no event in the log indicating Applocker blocked anything, nor does the usual prompt appear. There's just an indication in the Python command prompt indicating that it has been blocked by group policy. I created a path rule for Anaconda3 in Applocker, but that doesn't seem to matter. There's no central EXE to hash, just a collection of Python stuff. I cannot remove Applocker, nor am I 100% convinced it is the problem, but how do I get this piece of software to run?

Thanks

Comment: speak to your IT admin. Get restrictions lifted

Answer (score -1):

AppLocker has logs in the windows "Computer management" under Event Viewer/Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/AppLocker

[Applocker logs in Computer management.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd2J7.png)

In addition, I used total commander to find all exe and scripts in C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3 folder such as *.bat, *.cmd, *.vbs, *.ps1 and mainly *.js files. And copied them to one folder. Total commander has a function that you can rename all duplicates during copying so I got files named like XXX.js, XXX (1).js etc. And as long as the hash of files doesn't depend on the file name, I used all of these copies as exceptions for AppLocker.

Only be careful and before putting them into AppLocker delete all empty (0 bytes) files from that folder so you can add all files at once for every type of extension.
If you don't delete empty files AppLocker throws some error and stops adding the rest of the files.

In the screenshot, you can see an example of how I set it up in GPO/AppLocker.
You can notice that I splited JS files into 4 parts. But I did it before I figured out that I have to delete empty scripts.
[Example of my Applocker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze6mj.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1158383)

Comment: @Toto The essential part of the answer is in the text. Anyway,  I will try to add some additional information to the answer, tho.